# Bug in wikipedia page for Van Emde Boas tree?

Tags: data-structures

The [Wikipedia page for vEB trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) (specifically the [version from 27 September, 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Van_Emde_Boas_tree&oldid=861403073)),
gives the following pseudocode for finding the successor element of x in the vEB tree (of universe of size M):

```
function FindNext(T, x)
    if x < T.min then
        return T.min
    if x ≥ T.max then // no next element
        return M
    i = floor(x/√M)
    lo = x mod √M
    hi = x − lo
    if lo < T.children[i].max then
        return hi + FindNext(T.children[i], lo)
    return hi + T.children[FindNext(T.aux, i)].min
end
```

Consider the very last return statement. Shouldn't it instead be

```
    y = FindNext(T.aux, i)
    return y√M + T.children[y].min
```

Seems like a bug to me but I wanted to confirm.